# De Morgan`s Identities Understanding

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I am looking at the equation, and to me this reads:

On the left side, we have the points of X that does not exists in any of F.

On the right side I believe we take the intersection of all the points of X that does not exist in any of F.

However if these are points and not sets, the intersection of these points would make no sense cause intersection of two points does not mean anything(at least to me). However intersection of sets means something to me.

Now if that is true then on the left side we have all the set of x in X which is not in any of F.

However on the right hand side, we have the intersection of all the x in X which are not in any of F.

But it cant possible be a general rule that the union and intersection of a number of x in X are the same no matter how X looks like.

Hence my conclusion is that I don't understand the notation:

Could someone please help me demystify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal F$ is a collection of sets. That is, it is a set whose elements are sets themselves, not points. $\bigcup\limits_{F \in \mathcal F} F$ is the set consisting of all points that are in any of the sets $F$. So you are correct in your interpretation that $X \sim \bigcup\limits_{F \in \mathcal F} F$ is all the points that are in $X$, but not in any $F$.

On the right, again the $F$ are sets, and $X \sim F$ is the set of all points in $X$, but not in $F$. The intersection is an intersection of these sets over all the $F$ that are in $\mathcal F$. It is an intersection of sets, not points. In order for a point $x$ to be in this set, it has to be in $X \sim F$ for every $F \in \mathcal F$. That is, $x$ has to be in $X$, but not in $F$ for any $F \in \mathcal F$. Which is exactly the same description as the for the LHS, which is why the two are equal.

Comment: X~F I get is the set of all points in X but not in F. Lets call it U. However the intersection of U over all the F in F(fancy) what does this mean. If I have the intersection of U I get that, if I have the intersection of all F I get that. I do not get having intersection of U over all the F in F(fancy). Simply does not mean or make any sense to me, could you explain.

Comment: oh wait, is the intersection only concerned with the f in F(fancy)?

Comment: Now not I got it! Thank you!